# How can I control or anticipate the time that a caterpillar spends in its chrysalis?

Tags: entomology

My young daughter caught a caterpillar (*pararge aegeria*, to my non-expert eye) and we put it in a breathable jar with leaves, kept indoors in England. (Current climate is around 14-19 degrees Celcius at home, I have no specialist equipment to control the environment.)

In the last few days it has entered its pupil stage in a very dark brown chrysalis. I would like my daughter to be present at its emergence, if possible.

Is there anything I can do to either control the time that it emerges, or anticipate the time that it emerges?